# C# RegEx to match all in the second line

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex to match all in the second line.

```
First Line
Second Line
```

I have tried using \n(.*)\n but it returns the empty value.

```c#
Match match in Regex.Matches(line, @"\n(.*)\n", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Comment: Use `var match = Regex.Match(line, @"\n(.*)").Groups[1].Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `RegexOptions.MultiLine` enabled, you can use the following:

```
\n^(.*)$
```

When `Multiline` is enabled, `^` and `$` will match the beginning and the end of a line instead of the beginning and end of a string.

Example: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oodSMt/1)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for that. Just split input string on lines and get line which you need:

```
var line= @"First Line
Second Line";

var secondLine = line.Split('\n')[1]; // "Second Line"
```

You can also check count of lines in your string before getting required line by index to avoid `IndexOutOfRange` exception.

Even with regex it's better to use `Split` method if you are going to split input by some value (but again, it's an overkill if you are simply splitting by lines without some pattern):

```
 var secondLine = Regex.Split(line, Environment.NewLine)[1];
```

Comment: Using this on very long strings might create big overhead - if you expect very long strings you might be better off with a combination of .IndexOf() and .Substring(), to find the first 2 indexes of \n and creating a substring between those 2.

Comment: @Compufreak agree, but very long strings usually come from files. In that case I would simply use `File.ReadLines(fileName).Skip(n).FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to match two end of line while the your input only have one.

Change to `\n(.*)`

Comment: Or, better : \n(.*)(\n)? - this matches also if there is a third line.